# How to change the colour of links in Evolution

Tags: evolution

I assume that there is a default color defined somewhere for links (which is why I'm posting in the Elementary OS stackexchange). I'm new to Elementary, and liking it. The standard mail didn't quite fit my needs, so I started using Evolution. Quite happy with it, except for two things:

- When I click on a notification, I don't get sent to the message that was causing the notification.
- Links in e-mails are not visible, as they are white on a white background. The links in the headers (like from: and to:) are barely visible as they are white on light-gray.

Especially the latter is bugging me. Anybody here know how to change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- The first issue IMO depends on the application that generates the notification itself, so I'm not sure if there is anything to do about it.
- The second issue: I'm assuming you are using Evolution, but if you are using something different, just use the corresponding .desktop file for that email
  client:
  You could copy the desktop file from
  /usr/share/applications/evolution.desktop to ~/.local/share/applications
  and then, edit it and in the "Exec" line, just prepend the Adwaita GTK theme for that application. It will not have the "elementary look and feel" but at least you'll be able to read everything:
  Exec=env GTK_THEME=Adwaita evolution %U

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it seems something has been updated in the meantime (either Evolution or elemenatry), my links now are light blue, which is fine.